# Rounding value in swift results into a segmentation fault

Tags: swift, linux, segmentation-fault, glibc

I'm trying to round the following formula, if I uncomment one of the lines of code that should round my `binet` variable the program errors.

The return value will be casted to an int, this will truncate the float but is not preferable in this case.

```swift
#if os(macOS) || os(iOS)
import Darwin
#elseif os(Linux) || CYGWIN
import Glibc
#endif

func fibFormula(_ n: Int) -> Int {
  var binet = pow((pow(5, 0.5) + 1) / 2, Float(n)) / pow(5, 0.5)
  // binet = round(binet)
  // binet.round();
  return Int(binet)
}

print(fibFormula(5)) // Should output 5
```

Error:

```
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /usr/bin/swift -frontend -interpret fib.swift -disable-objc-interop -color-diagnostics -module-name fib -- 5 
/usr/bin/swift(+0x42e1b54)[0x55f476d0bb54]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x42df93e)[0x55f476d0993e]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x42e1d12)[0x55f476d0bd12]
/usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x13d00)[0x7fdf098bfd00]
[0x7fdf099243fa]
[0x7fdf099241ea]
/usr/bin/swift(+0xd7f095)[0x55f4737a9095]
/usr/bin/swift(+0xd82fe0)[0x55f4737acfe0]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x607d13)[0x55f473031d13]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x5df088)[0x55f473009088]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x5da4c2)[0x55f4730044c2]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x58bea1)[0x55f472fb5ea1]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x7fdf090f7ee3]
/usr/bin/swift(+0x58a2be)[0x55f472fb42be]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Can anyone help me resolve this error?** I'm pretty new to swift and I'm using Linux.

Edit:
When I try my code in [a sandbox](https://www.weheartswift.com/swift-sandbox/) it works with using the `round` function. Maybe this is a `Glibc` issue?

A more readable version of the formula (also different method, same results):

```
import Glibc
func fibFormula2(_ n: Int) -> Int {
  let sqrt5 = sqrt(5)
  let phi = (sqrt5 + 1) / 2
  let binet = pow(phi, Double(n)) / sqrt5
  return Int(round(binet))
}
print(fibFormula2(5)) // Should output 5
```